# Twitter Analytics on Inactive Account

Tags: twitter

Twitter Analytics is available on one of the Twitter accounts I manage. This account was moderately active previously, but has been inactive for the last few months. The account follows less than 50 people and is followed by less than 50 people, with unprotected Tweets.

Twitter Analytics often shows increases in the number of profile views and Tweet impressions on this account. What would be causing this?